# Not able to NGINX log where the request is getting forwarded

Tags: nginx, nginx-reverse-proxy

There are multiple nginx conf in my system and I want to debug where nginx is forwading the request for debugging purpose.

I wanted see in the nginx log with the proxy_pass value

```
location /api/superadmin/ {
        proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:9039;
    }
```

For example in the logs

`119.82.108.182 - - [18/Dec/2023:09:06:37 +0000] "GET /api/superadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 200 52 "-" "PostmanRuntime/7.29.0" "-"`

In the above log wanted to see `proxy_pass` value as well for debugging. How to check this?

Answer (score 0):

The `log_format` and `access_log` directives allow you to customise the access log or even generate multiple access logs for different purposes. See [the log module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html).

Logging `$server_name` and `$server_port` will help identify which `server { ... }` block handled the request, by showing the value of the `server_name` and `listen` directives within that block. Or `-` if the server name is missing.

Logging `$proxy_host` and `$proxy_port` will help identify which proxy the request was forwarded to using `proxy_pass`. Or `-` if the request was handled differently.

For example, the following statements placed in the `http` block, will append the above information to `test.log`, for requests to any `server` block:

```
log_format test '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
                '"$request" $status $body_bytes_sent '
                '"$server_name:$server_port" "$proxy_host:$proxy_port"';

access_log /var/log/nginx/test.log test;
```

*Change the `access_log` logfile path to match the one used by your OS.*